# Why do we consider the shortest length (displacement) for doing the calculations?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work, vectors

Whenever we calculate any lengths in Physics, we tend to express using displacements. For example, while calculating energy, which is given by the formula- 
**E = Fs**
where **E** represents the energy, **F** represents force applied and **s** represents displacement.
Why do we use the shortest distance to calculate, shouldn't the total energy required or spent, be calculated with actual length of the movement?

Comment: No? We use integration of all the tiny little steps, so that there is no ambiguity

Answer (score 6):

The definition you wrote down is not the most general definition of work. There are two important points here.

For a general force ${\bf F}$, $$W = \int_{\text{along the path}} {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf s}$$
where we are indeed summing along the path instead of just using the total displacement vector ${\bf s}$. If the force is constant throughout the path, this simplifies to your formula (for a straight path).

Now for a [conservative force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force) (like gravity), the work done only depends on the endpoints and not the path. This is known as path independence.

Comment: So basically, how we consider displacement varies according to the system we are working in. Right?

Comment: Not exactly. The definition of displacement of the particle can be the same (almost always is) for two systems. What this formula tells you is that whatever the path is, you have to think about the work done at each tiny step of it and add them up. It’s not enough to consider the total displacement but you really (in the general case) have to sum up the tiny increments of work throughout the whole path

Answer (score 3):

In case you are doing algebra-based physics as opposed to the more rigorous calculus-based physics as in the other examples, then the $s$ in your formula always represents the total distance over which the force acts. When the force acts over a straight line, then the distance is actually the shortest distance between the two points that represent the initial and final points of the motion considered. For straight lines, the cases of "shortest distance" and "total distance coincide". As JohnA. notes in his post, conservative forces have the property of path independence, thus regardless of the actual curvilinear distance traveled, one may as well use the straight line distance parallel with the direction of force to compute the desired work. For a force like gravity this would be the vertical displacement, which in general may be less than the total distance of path.